# Exception being thrown during mocking

Tags: junit, mockito

I want to mock out a situation where if the service is called with a specific set of inputs, it should return a value, but if it's called with any other inputs throw an exception. So I've got:

```
doThrow(new ValidationException()).when(mockService).thing(any(), any());
when(mockService.thing(EXPECTED_PARAM_1, EXPECTED_PARAM_2).thenReturn(mockResult);
```

But when I go to run my test it throws the ValidationException on that second line where I'm creating the mock. It seems as though that second line is being treated as if I was actually calling the service, and since I'm mocking it with params that fit the any() any() it's throwing the exception rather than setting up the additional mock.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `when.thenReturn` actually calls the method it's mocking exactly once when the mock is first setup. Since the previous mock setup the default scenario where anytime the method is called it should thrown the exception, the second mock when it does its initial single call triggers the first mock and throws.
The solution to this scenario is to switch the second mock to use `doReturn.when` instead, as it never actually calls the method.